# Counting number of elements in a character column by levels of a factor column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have a dataframe in which there are two factor columns. One column is a company column, second is a product column. There are several missing values in product column and so I want to count the number of values in product column for each company (or each level of the company variable). I tried table, and count function in plyr package but they only seem to work with numeric variables. Please help!
Lets say the data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(company= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"), product = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA))
```

So the output I am looking for is -

A 2
B 2
C 3
D 2

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try `aggregate(product~company, df1, FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), na.action = NULL)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dplyr solution.

```
df %>% 
    filter(!is.na(product)) %>% 
    group_by(company) %>% 
    count()

# A tibble: 4 × 2
    comp     n
  <fctr> <int>
1      A     2
2      B     2
3      C     3
4      D     1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! My final goal is to calculate proportions i.e. for each level of company column, I want the total count of product non-missing values for that company divided by the total count of product non-missing values for the whole product column. So taking the same e.g. as above, if company A has 2 product values that are non-missing, and the total non-missing product values in the whole column across all companies is 7, then I want 2/7 for A and so on. Can this be accommodated in the same code as you suggested?

Comment: Should be able to, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your df is :

**CASE 1)** As give in question

**Data for df:**

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
comp <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D","D" )
prod <- c(1,1,2,3,4,3,3,1,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(comp=comp,prod=prod)
```

**Program:**

```
df$prodflag <- !is.na(df$prod)
tapply(df$prodflag , df$comp,sum)
```

**Output**:

```
> tapply(df$prodflag , df$comp,sum)
A B C D 
2 2 3 1 

#########################################################################
```

**CASE 2)** In case stringsAsFactors is on and prod is in characters, even NAs are quoted as characters and marked as factors then you  can do:

**Data:**

```
comp <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D","D" )
prod <- c("a","a","b","c","d","c","c","a","NA","NA")
df <- data.frame(comp=comp,prod=prod,stringsAsFactors = T)
```

**Solution:**

```
df$prodflag <- as.numeric(!as.character(df$prod)=="NA")
tapply(df$prodflag , df$comp,sum)

#########################################################################
```

**CASE 3)** In case the prod is a character and stringsAsFactors is on but NAs are not quoted then you can do:

**Data:**

```
comp <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D","D" )
prod <- c("a","a","b","c","d","c","c","a",NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(comp=comp,prod=prod,stringsAsFactors = T)
```

**Solution:**

```
df$prodflag <- as.numeric(!is.na(df$prod))
tapply(df$prodflag , df$comp,sum)
```

Moral of the story, we should understand our data and then we can the logic which best suits our need.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution would have otherwise worked but I forgot to mention that my product column is actually a factor column and the values in it are character strings. To keep things simple I had put numeric values... I did try tapply but that did not seem to work for counting char and factor columns

Comment: @user3816784 The solution would still work you just need to tweak it for the changes you have said, see the edit i have made.

Comment: Thank you so much! It cleared a very important confusion in my mind regarding how to treat blanks and NAs

Comment: Case 3 applies to me - i.e. prod was a factor column with string elements, and blanks are taken as a level as well. However if I run df$prodflag <- as.numeric(!is.na(df$prod)) or df$prodflag <- as.numeric(!as.character(df$prod)=="NA") I get error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

Comment: I imported the data file, with prod column as string and company column as factor. Then If I ran tapply I get the error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument" I finally did it by subsetting for each company as follows. This is a long winded way but works... I was looking for a facet like functionality in ggplot where you can summarize data in a column by levels of a factor var except that I am dealing with a string column instead of numeric.

Comment: For each company -  >sum(df[df$company=="A",]$prod != "")

Comment: @user3816784 it is very difficult for me to understand what you are trying to achieve. Let me see if i am able to arrange a chat forum in stackoverflow  where we can discuss your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help! Since I am a beginner and have less than 20 reputation I am unable to participate in a chat forum.

Comment: @user3816784 do a `str(df)` you your dataframe, what does it tell you about the prod column, is it a a character,factor etc.

Comment: @user3816784 , also you can do `dput(head(dataframe,20))` or if you want to sample then use somehting like `dput(df[c(sample(1:nrow(df),20)),])` to get the structure, paste it here. In . that way i get to copy the structure of your data and can run the above code and understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum` from `base R`

```
with(df, rowsum(+!is.na(prod), comp))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! My final goal is to calculate proportions i.e. for each level of company column, I want the total count of product non-missing values for that company divided by the total count of product non-missing values for the whole product column. So taking the same e.g. as above, if company A has 2 product values that are non-missing, and the total non-missing product values in the whole column across all companies is 7, then I want 2/7 for A and so on. Can this be accommodated in the same code as you suggested?

Comment: @user3816784  You may check `?prop.table`